# Axios not working with very simple 'get' method in Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, axios

How can it be that this super simple code using Axios with Typescript, is causing an error?:

```
import axios from 'axios'

axios.get('https://www.google.com').then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data);
});
```

Runing:

```
ts-node index.ts
```

Gives me the following error:

```
axios.get('https://www.google.com').then((response) => {
      ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')
    at Object.<anonymous> (src/index.ts:25:7)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
    at Module.m._compile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1618:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1621:12)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:82:12)
    at phase4 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/bin.ts:649:14)
    at bootstrap (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/bin.ts:95:10)
```

tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017"
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Axios isn't loaded properly, just like the error is saying

Comment: It seems that `axios` isn't installed.

Comment: did you run `yarn install axios` or `npm install axios` (or add it to your `package.json` and then run `npm install` or `yarn install`)?

Comment: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5011